# How To Create a Bootable Clone of boot disk

Tags: boot, backup

In my environment I have 2 MAC Minis, a Windows10 machine, and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  On the MAC minis, I run SuperDuper to create a bootable clone on an external hard disk.  Is it possible to do the same thing on Ubuntu?  I saw an earlier answer to this, but it involved many steps monkeying around with dd, /etc/fstab and grub, and is several years old.  Is there a new and better way?  I considered Clonezilla but it doesn't specifically say on their web page that it will create a bootable clone.  I want my solution for the Ubuntu machine to work like SuperDuper does for my MACs.

Comment: Try installing clonezilla from your Ubuntu Synaptic Package Manager and report back on it's usefulness.

Comment: OK, started Clonezilla installation and preparation of external hard drive.  Will post back results as requested.

Comment: 1) Installed Ubuntu Synaptic Package Manager - successful.
2) Installed Clonezilla via SPM - successful.
3) After installing Clonezilla on internal hard drive, it appears that Clonezilla must be downloaded and burned to a DVD.
4) Used Disks app to format USB external disk as Linux ext4 bootable.
5) Downloaded Clonezilla iso to MAC Mini, burned to dvd.
6) Booted Clonezilla on Ubuntu machine, chose device-device option.
7) Answered all questions, clone process begins …
8) Operation failed - target disk too small - source disk 976773168 sectors, target disk 976773167 sectors. [Cont'd]

Comment: Seriously?  Both drives claim to be 500GB.
9) Responded reboot to Clonezilla prompt.
10) System attempted to boot off USB external disk, which of course failed.
11) Shut down system, removed USB external disk, restarted system, booted from 
internal hard drive.
12) System back up after normal boot.  
13) Remounted USB external hard drive.
14) Rebooted again to ensure system boots off of internal drive, which it did, however, no longer detects USB external hard drive.

Comment: So: now what?  Why isn't the external USB drive being detected?

Answer (score 4):

My first answer does not clone the system in general.  I have succeeded in cloning everything and making it bootable.  (This is for EFI|UEFI, including Mac, not MBR booting.)

The device configuration:

```
mac2011-linux% lsblk -f|grep -v loop
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                           
├─sda1 vfat     FAT32 EFI                 67E3-17ED                             172.8M    12% /boot/efi
├─sda2 hfsplus        SSD 1T              0492d65c-8b14-356a-9d3d-337f44e8d58a                
├─sda3 hfsplus        Recovery HD         87867aee-1d5c-3c9e-ae36-8d2df5c162f1                
└─sda4 ext4     1.0                       dc68435c-f80c-4beb-a09b-69015ad516e6  161.5G    60% /
sdb                                                                                           
├─sdb1 vfat     FAT32 EFI                 B4A1-A82A                             172.8M    12% /media/alba/EFI
├─sdb2 ext4     1.0   Ubuntu backup       e370d38b-7cdf-4a2a-b9e5-cc4ff1723f51    165G    59% /media/alba/Ubun
├─sdb4 hfsplus        Mac OS X El Capitan 3771b656-357f-3ac4-a993-704353fc89b7                
└─sdb5 hfsplus        Recovery HD         1925d052-aca6-307a-8025-ad6321a399f4
```

Check that all the above four partitions are mounted and mount them if necessary (with Ubuntu Disks).

`sdb2` (Ubuntu backup) is the intended clone of the Ubuntu system and user files, shortly, the root partition.  As `sdb` is an external device, `sdb2` is mounted by default as `/media/alba/Ubuntu backup`.  `sdb1` is the intended clone of the EFI system partition, mounted as `/media/alba/EFI`.

Each partition must have a different UUID.  FAT partition UUID can be changed only by formatting.  The clone partitions should be large enough to contain all the files of the original partitions.

Clone the root partition:

```
sudo rsync --archive --executability --hard-links --update --verbose --xattrs --one-file-system --delete --progress --exclude={/etc/fstab,/boot/grub/grub.cfg,/export,/home/alba/.cache,"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*",/lost+found} / /media/alba/Ubuntu\ backup
```

The contents of `/dev` etc. do not need to be copied because they are useless or should not be copied because Ubuntu creates them.   However Ubuntu won't boot if `/dev` etc. do not exist, so only `/dev/*` not `/dev` etc. are excluded.

I also exclude `/export` that is a NFS mount in my configuration.  Not excluding `/export` may cause duplicates.

Copy `/etc/fstab` from original to clone:

```
mac2011-linux% sudo cp /etc/fstab /media/alba/Ubuntu\ backup/etc/fstab
```

In `/media/alba/Ubuntu\ backup/etc/fstab`, replace the original root and EFI system partition UUIDs by the UUIDs found in device configuration above, so that:

```
mac2011-linux% sudo cat /media/alba/Ubuntu\ backup/etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=e370d38b-7cdf-4a2a-b9e5-cc4ff1723f51 /               ext4    errors=remount
-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=B4A1-A82A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw            
  0       0
```

Copy the EFI system partition:

```
mac2011-linux% sudo -i                                        
root@mac2011-linux:~# cp -r /boot/efi/* /media/alba/EFI
```

Edit `/media/alba/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` to define root partition, so that:

```
root@mac2011-linux:~# cat /media/alba/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
search.fs_uuid e370d38b-7cdf-4a2a-b9e5-cc4ff1723f51 root hd1,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Partition numbers in GRUB are the same as in Ubuntu.

Copy `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from original to clone (as you did for `/etc/fstab`) and make it writable:

```
root@mac2011-linux:~# chmod +w /media/alba/Ubuntu\ backup/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Replace everywhere `gpt4` by `gpt2` and original root partition UUID by clone root partition UUID.

Reset permission:

```
root@mac2011-linux:~# chmod -w /media/alba/Ubuntu\ backup/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Reboot, select the clone EFI in the firmware boot menu.  If you made no mistake, then GRUB will launch Ubuntu, else it will prompt.

**Remarks**

I have checked in he GRUB shell that the GRUB device number `hd0` used in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` does not refer to any of the `/dev/sdb?`.  It is not necessary to edit it.

I advise to disconnect the original at least once while booting the clone in order to make sure that the clone can boot by itself.  If you don't want to open the computer case, you can just check that the original partitions can be unmounted after booting on the clone.

`update-grub` is not needed but once you have booted on clone you can update GRUB and reboot on clone to check that the clone is still bootable.

Using `--delete-excluded` in `rsync` would wipe out the edits of `/media/alba/Ubuntu\ backup/etc/fstab` and `/media/alba/Ubuntu\ backup/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

In [Bash script to backup/clone Ubuntu to another partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition/1028605#1028605) is a script that does very similar things.

It is better first to clone manually in order to understand and check every step, and only later script, according to the system peculiarities.

The copying and editing `/etc/fstab`, `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and the EFI system partition should be repeated if those files change on the original.  This happens during system updates.

**Bibliography or references**

[Does rsync requires changing UUID after copying a partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190955/does-rsync-requires-changing-uuid-after-copying-a-partition)

[Dual boot and the files /boot/grub/grub.cfg — which one is used?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752627/dual-boot-and-the-files-boot-grub-grub-cfg-which-one-is-used/1068993#1068993)

[UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

[GRUB starts in command line after reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot)

[How to Rescue a Non-booting GRUB 2 on Linux](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/)

[Bash script to backup/clone Ubuntu to another partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition/1028605#1028605)

[File system cloning Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rsync#File_system_cloning)

Comment: I'm the author of your last link. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Thanks for the script.  I should write a script like yours but I am lazy.  I have made a second clone in 20 minutes (excluding the rsync time).  The method is simple and useful: if my install breaks down for any reason, like a foul system upgrade (which was your motivation), or a disk failure, I can switch to the clone and keep going,  I don't even need to repair the original but if I want to I can do it more easily from the clone.

Comment: I make clones to test new Ubuntu versions rather than performing upgrades on the original and risk breakage.

Comment: `/etc/fstab` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` should be copied only the first time, then edited and excluded from the subsequent backups but not deleted.  Other files that do not exist on the original should be deleted on the clone in order to avoid overfilling the clone. I need to arrange this.

Comment: `rsync` used by your last link does delete new files in the clone to avoid running out of disk space and ensure 100% reproduction of the original. `/etc/fstab` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` are automatically edited each time the script is run. No end-user editing is required.

Comment: I have interrupted single device (ordinary) booting at GRUB command line to check my theory about GRUB device naming.  It occurs that there is nothing in (hd0) and that the root partition is (hd1,gpt*).  This contradicts `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` that contains only `set root='hd0,gpt*'`.  I have also noticed by chance that (hd*,gpt*) does not matter in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`.  The (hd*,gpt*) is indeed redundant with UUID and GRUB may be smart enough to work only with UUID.

Comment: Thanks, Pierre, for answering and creating the script. For me, it did not work since I still had to copy images of each partition. I created a repo with additional steps and a description of how I did it (my task was basically to create 50 Ubuntu SSD drives that students can use as independent OS). https://github.com/maxiuw/ubuntu_ssd_boot

Answer (score 1):

Create the necessary partitions, set the labels are run the script with both devices attached.

```
#!/bin/zsh
# automates the method explained in
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267225/how-to-create-a-bootable-clone-of-boot-disk/1327623#1327623
# USE CAREFULLY, THIS IS INTRINSICALLY DANGEROUS SOFTWARE
# Pierre ALBARÈDE 2021/4/24
# tested with Ubuntu 20.10

# Assumptions:
# - /boot is not on a separate partition.
# - root partition has label $UbuntuLabel and the first partition on the same device is the EFI system partition,
# - root partition backup has label $UbuntuBackupLabel and the first partition on the same device is available for the EFI system partition backup,
# - device names are like sd[a-z].

# To do:
# - pick and exclude duplicate mount (e. g. for NFS) from /etc/fstab to avoid overfilling the backup device,
# -check that backup volume partition sizes are enough.

# --- begin config
UbuntuLabel='Ubuntu'
UbuntuBackupLabel='Ubuntu backup'
logfile="rsync.log"
# excluded from rsync
# /swapfile can be big and transfering it is a waste of time,
# not having a swapfile backup makes some errors at boot and shutdown.
# excludedByUser='/export,"/home/*/.cache",/swapfile,$logfile'
excludedByUser='/export,"/home/*/.cache",$logfile'
# --- end config

# Partition attributes are named as in
# % lsblk -PO /dev/sda1
# [filtered]
# NAME="sda1" PATH="/dev/sda1" FSTYPE="vfat" FSUSED="24.1M" FSUSE%="12%" FSVER="FAT32" MOUNTPOINT="/boot/efi" LABEL="EFI" UUID="67E3-17ED" PTUUID="b5ca7ab4-d564-49a1-a43b-d9125d4dcbab" PTTYPE="gpt" PARTTYPE="c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b" PARTTYPENAME="EFI System" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="05bdacf6-78ff-451d-8c4d-bb812fd68e83" PKNAME="sda"
 
# Many attributes look similar, I use LABEL and UUID, not PARTLABEL and PTUUID, PARTUUID.

alias lsblkn='lsblk -n'

#########
# TESTS #
#########

# Are all UUIDs distinct?
[[ -n $(lsblkn -o UUID|grep '\S'|sort|uniq --repeated) ]]&&{echo "Error: not all UUIDs are distinct.  Did you use dd?";exit 1}

# Does only one partition exists with LABEL $UbuntuLabel?
[[ $(lsblkn -o LABEL|grep -x $UbuntuLabel|wc -l) != 1 ]]&&{echo "Error: $UbuntuLabel is not unique.";exit 1}

# Does only one partition exists with LABEL $UbuntuBackupLabel?
[[ $(lsblkn -o LABEL|grep -x $UbuntuBackupLabel|wc -l) != 1 ]]&&{echo "Error: $UbuntuBackupLabel is not unique.";exit 1}

#######################################
# DETERMINE PARTITION PATHS AND UUIDS #
#######################################
# paths for mount
# UUIDs for (display and) replacement in config files

# blkid (or findfs) finds only one occurrence, that is why I have checked unicity
UbuntuPath=$(blkid --label $UbuntuLabel)
UbuntuBackupPath=$(blkid --label $UbuntuBackupLabel)

devicePath=/dev/$(lsblkn -o PKNAME $UbuntuPath)
deviceBackupPath=/dev/$(lsblkn -o PKNAME $UbuntuBackupPath)

UbuntuUUID=$(lsblkn -o UUID $UbuntuPath)
echo "Ubuntu partition UUID:            $UbuntuUUID"

# EFI is always first partition with number 1
EFIPath="$devicePath"1
EFIUUID=$(lsblkn -o UUID $EFIPath)
echo "EFI system partition UUID:        $EFIUUID"

UbuntuBackupUUID=$(lsblkn -o UUID $UbuntuBackupPath)
echo "Ubuntu backup partition UUID:     $UbuntuBackupUUID"

EFIBackupPath="$deviceBackupPath"1
EFIBackupUUID=$(lsblkn -o UUID $EFIBackupPath)
echo "EFI system partition backup UUID: $EFIBackupUUID"

# determine GRUB partition number from Ubuntu partition name
# on original
UbuntuGpt=$(echo $UbuntuPath|sed "s/\/dev\/sd[a-z]/gpt/")
# on backup
UbuntuBackupGpt=$(echo $UbuntuBackupPath|sed "s/\/dev\/sd[a-z]/gpt/")

# I don't know how to determine GRUB device number but it does not matter so it is not changed (it is 0).


#########
# mount #
#########

# If we are here, Ubuntu must be mounted.

[[ -z $(findmnt $EFIPath) ]]&&{echo "Mounting EFI system partition.";udisksctl mount --block-device $EFIPath}

[[ -z $(findmnt $UbuntuBackupPath) ]]&&{echo "Mounting Ubuntu backup partition.";udisksctl mount --block-device $UbuntuBackupPath}

[[ -z $(findmnt $EFIBackupPath) ]]&&{echo "Mounting EFI system partition backup.";udisksctl mount --block-device $EFIBackupPath}

# All 4 partition are now mounted.

# determine destination mountpoints
# UbuntuBackupMountPoint should normally be /media/$USER/$UbuntuBackupLabel
UbuntuBackupMountPoint=$(lsblkn -o MOUNTPOINT "$UbuntuBackupPath")
EFIBackupMountPoint=$(lsblkn -o MOUNTPOINT "$deviceBackupPath"1)

echo "You are going to backup to:"
echo $UbuntuBackupMountPoint
echo $EFIBackupMountPoint

read -q "REPLY?Confirm by typing y?"

[[ $REPLY != 'y' ]]&&{echo "\nExiting without file change.";exit 0}
echo "\nProceeding with rsync."

##########
# BACKUP #
##########

# rsync would not transfer /etc/fstab and /boot/grub/grub.cfg and /media/$USER/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg after their backups have been edited and given a more recent date so I erase the backups. One could also cheat the modification time.

sudo rm $UbuntuBackupMountPoint{/etc/fstab,/boot/grub/grub.cfg}
sudo rm $EFIBackupMountPoint/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg

# Backup root partition, including /etc/fstab /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# --archive = -rlptgoD
# --recursive, -r          recurse into directories
# --links, -l              copy symlinks as symlinks
# --perms, -p              preserve permissions
# --times, -t              preserve modification times
# --owner, -o              preserve owner (super-user only)
# --group, -g              preserve group
# -D          <             equivalent to --devices --specials
# --devices                preserve device files (super-user only)

# To debug, replace "rsync" by "echo" or use '--dry-run.
# Single quotes prevent eval to remove double quote around "/dev/*" and split words in '$UbuntuBackupLabel'.

eval sudo rsync --log-file=$logfile --archive --no-D --executability --hard-links --update --verbose --xattrs --one-file-system --delete --progress --exclude={$excludedByUser} --exclude={'"/dev/*"','"/proc/*"','"/sys/*"','"/tmp/*"','"/run/*"','"/mnt/*"','"/media/*"','"/lost+found/*"',$logfile} --delete-excluded / '$UbuntuBackupMountPoint'

# backup the EFI system partition
sudo rsync --recursive --times --delete /boot/efi/ $EFIBackupMountPoint

###############
# EDIT BACKUP #
###############

sudo sed -i "s/$EFIUUID/$EFIBackupUUID/g;s/$UbuntuUUID/$UbuntuBackupUUID/g" $UbuntuBackupMountPoint/etc/fstab

grubcfg=$UbuntuBackupMountPoint/boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo chmod +w $grubcfg
sudo sed -i "s/$UbuntuUUID/$UbuntuBackupUUID/g;s/$UbuntuGpt/$UbuntuBackupGpt/g" $grubcfg
sudo chmod -w $grubcfg

# set root UUID in EFI
sed -i "s/$UbuntuUUID/$UbuntuBackupUUID/;s/$UbuntuGpt/$UbuntuBackupGpt/" $EFIBackupMountPoint/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
exit 0
```

Comment: should you run is as UbuntuLabel='/dev/sdb', UbuntuBackupLabel='/dev/sdc' after partition table of sdb is copied to sdc, or you should copy only the efi partition to efi partition i.e. from your post above it would be UbuntuLabel='/dev/sda1' to UbuntuBackupLabel='/dev/sdb1'

Comment: This is confusing: UbuntuLabel='/dev/sdb'.  Partition must be mounted for ` rsync` .  I use LABEL not PATH.  This is high level backup, not imaging,  Individual files can be updated separately.

Answer (score 0):

As for cloenzilla, check that the destination drive/partition is formatted. And then in Clonezilla choose expert mode and enable the “-icds” option. You need to also  choose "Resize partitional table proportionally" option. Your external should come back if you turn off, remove cable, reboot, wait then reconect the external. Type 'lsblk' to confirm it's there.

Comment: I would not recommend expert mode for a first time user.

Comment: I'm used to the MAC and Window machines auto-detecting the USB disk when they boot up.  I guess Ubuntu Linux is different.  When I unplug and then reconnect the device, it IS detected.  So far I have managed to create an img file on the external disk, and Clonezilla says the image is restorable, which is OK, but no better than what I could do on my Windows machine.  I will try your suggestion about expert mode.

Comment: Regarding Organic Marble's comments, I've nothing to lose; I did a minimum installation and there's no data files to lose yet.  In my opinion, there's no point in continuing with Ubuntu until I can make restorable backups, and with the img file I'm halfway there.  Will still try for bootable clone.

Comment: I would stick with clonezilla but I have to agree it is overly complicated and Organic Marble is correct. Without sending you up the garden path, you could explore gparted as it does have cloning features and is easier to use but it is also easier to delete entire drives at the click of a button! so beware. Here is one opinion piece https://www.ubuntupit.com/top-15-best-disk-cloning-software-for-linux/

Comment: I just tried to restore the image I took earlier, and the only options shown on my menu are savedisk, savepart, and exit.  I do NOT see options for restoredisk, or any of the other options shown on the several tutorials I've tried to follow.  So far, I am not impressed with Clonezilla.

Comment: Assuming you are booting from clonezilla USB or disk and get through all the language and keyboard choices, does this help? https://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=./clonezilla-live/doc/02_Restore_disk_image/05-start-clonezilla-or-cmd.doc#05-start-clonezilla-or-cmd.doc

Comment: No, that's what I've been doing.  Question: I downloaded the Clonezilla iso on my MAC and burned the Clonezilla live CD from there.  Does the fact that I downloaded CZ on my MAC create an issue?  I've seen cases where the host checks the operating system before starting the download on the presumption that you can't say, run a Linux app on the MAC.

Comment: I am closing this thread.  Clearly I'm not doing something right but I'm unable to discover what it is, and I'm frankly tired of trying to get this to work.  I will seek other solutions.  Thanks to those who offered to help.

Answer (score 0):

> I run SuperDuper to create a bootable clone on an external hard disk. Is it possible to do the same thing on Ubuntu?

Although there is no tool out there like CCC (Bombich) or Super Duper for Mac OS,  I think I have done it roughly, at least with EFI booting and a single user.

**Introduction**

If you make a complete clone with `dd` then it will take a very long time so you can't do it too often (like every day).  Moreover you may have trouble using both devices at the same time as they have initially the same identifiers (UUID).

I have read in Clonezilla documentation that it does not have the incremental feature so I did not search further.  You need an incremental copy program, that is `rsync`.

Identity must be set consistently on each device for booting.

Also, in order to copy from original to clone, at least, both should be mounted simultaneously, so they should have different UUIDs.

**Technical details**

Device identity lies in exactly three locations:

1. `/etc/fstab`.
2. `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`
3. `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

`/boot/efi` is just a mount of the EFI system partition = EFS.

**How to**

On the intended clone, create a FAT partition about same size as the original EFS.  Copy the EFS with `cp -r`: there are few small files and they will rarely change.  As FAT does not know about permissions, so you don't have to worry about them.

Also create a Linux partition, similar to the one you want to clone (e. g. ext4).

Create a Ubuntu live USB, as explained elsewhere.  You can use Startup Disk Creator.

Power off.  Disconnect you original device from your computer, to make sure it won´t be corrupted (this requires some screwdriver playing).

Connect the intended clone.  Install Ubuntu thereon from the Ubuntu live USB, creating one user with the same name as original.

If you have files from a previous attempt, in order to save time, choose "Something else" in the install menu and do not reformat.

The Ubuntu installer with hopefully fill correctly the EFS, `/etc/fstab`, `/boot/efi` and `/boot/grub`.

Check that Ubuntu boots on the intended clone.

Power off.  Disconnect the intended clone.  Reconnect the original.  Reboot.  Reconnect the intended clone (externally, by USB or Firewire).  With Disks, check the intended clone mount and set $MOUNT to it.  Fill the intended clone with

```
sudo rsync -aEHuvX --progress --exclude={"/etc/fstab","/export",".cache","/dev","/proc","/sys","/tmp","/run","/mnt","/media","/lost+found","/cdrom","/srv","/swapfile","/boot"} / $MOUNT
```

`/etc/fstab` `/boot` must be excluded to preserve clone boot-ability.  Other excludes concern temporary, duplicate, auxiliary files that should not be copied because that will take time or may cause trouble.  You can add `--delete` to save space.

Power off.  Replace original by intended clone.  Check reboot and clone functionality.

**Defects found on the clone**

- Evolution fails : "evolution-alarm-notify crashed" and "settings schema not installed".
- Login shell on clone is bash, whereas it was zsh on original.
- Many Gnome desktop shortcuts don't work.

I missed something to copy correctly user database or settings.

Please improve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have a big backup disk, but if you have, you can copy by ISO using GNOME Disks.

step 1: create a disk image on your backup disk

step 2: restore disk image on your new disk

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What the original poster wanted and what I actually did is a bootable BACKUP, not exactly a clone, because the UUIDs on the backup differ from the UUIDs on the original.  On Mac OS, CCC and Super Duper must work likewise, because both the original must be mounted simultaneously to partly update the backup with `rsync` (or `cp`).

If you really you want a clone, you can use `dd` but it can take long (depending on your interface speed and the data size  -- through Firewire so it takes hours to move 300 GB). The outcome of `dd` is uncertain because it is very low level and it can be dangerous.  Also, it will reproduce the original with all sorts of useless or annoying details, while `rsync` will somehow clean the file system (e. g. not copy a broken file).  The clone should be good to fully replace the original but not good to mount alongside to recover a lost file.

For some reason that I do not understand, few Linux people are interested in bootable backup or want to communicate about it.

However, backing up in a few seconds and having a backup that can be booted in a minute is a great security.  Reinstalling a complete Linux with all my customizations and programs takes me maybe one or two days, or can be a kill, if I am on a trip or if I have a deadline.

The backup script I have posted is roughly correct (although it can be improved greatly and lacks generality).  It worked with Ubuntu until July 2022 (up to this date, it was 22.04).

I moved to Fedora 36 in August 2022 for other reasons.  I adapted the backup script.  At the beginning of September, it ceased to work.  I checked again in Ubuntu (up to date) and it did not work either, while it still worked on a July Ubuntu backup.

I upgraded Fedora to 37 (F37) some weeks ago.  I returned to the backup problem, making tests with two machines other than my principal machine, as these tests are very dangerous, all the more because I don't have a bootable backup!  This can be a costly hobby, as three computers are needed to be comfortable.

I discovered than I could no more install F37 on my Macbook pros.  I also discovered that F37 is not portable, that is, if I move it to another machine, it won't boot.  Also, Fedora puts a lot of things in the EFS and uses the HFS+ format for the EFS (while even Apple uses FAT).

Considering the complex situation in Fedora, I began trying Manjaro a few days ago.  Manjaro's EFS is very simple (containing only two useful files).  The backup script works again on a fresh installation of Manjaro.  I have moved all my stuff to Manjaro and checked that the backup script still works.

The bootable backup topic is not specific to Ubuntu, so it should go to the Unix Stack Exchange.  I may have some time to share on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your update.  I'm glad to see that there is some interest in creating a bootable backup.  I also thought your comments on Fedora and Manjaro were timely.

Frankly, I haven't played with Ubuntu since my original post.  I haven't had much luck with getting things like the DVD player (the one with the orange traffic cone) to work properly, and if I can't make a bootable backup, then, frankly, there's not much point to continuing ...

... although I would like to see an article on taking an image.  If I can create an installation DVD with the software to restore an image from an external drive to the hard disk, that would be acceptable, because then the process would work like Windows.  Not great, mind you, but acceptable.

Comment: Then you could try Manjaro, because many things work directly there.  In particular, no trackpad problems on Macbook pro.  You may try to make disk images as explained in earlier answers (Clonezilla or `dd`).  You won' t go far with DVD player since capacity is limited, except maybe Blu Ray, which won' t work with old Firewire Macs.